# Backup Failed when using the Backups application

Tags: backup

I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1546, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1540, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1375, in main
    action = commandline.ProcessCommandLine(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1132, in ProcessCommandLine
    globals.backend = backend.get_backend(args[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 223, in get_backend
    obj = get_backend_object(url_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 209, in get_backend_object
    return factory(pu)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/giobackend.py", line 97, in __init__
    self.remote_file.make_directory_with_parents(None)
Error: g-io-error-quark: Operation unsupported (15)
```

Comment: I do not know how to do it, not a nerd :)

Comment: Of late, on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I am getting this notification, "Encryption Password Needed" to BACKUP. Completely clueless about what and how to do  it? Which password?  How to change if it is forgotten? ;-)